# How can I make a nested query in view

Tags: entities, views

I have 2 content type (article and Album).

In articles I choose one or more albums using node references (autocomplete) to display it with the article, but I need only albums that are not added before in any articles to be appear in autocomplete not all albums

I try to make a view but I can't find how to make a nested query to select all albums title where id not in filed_article_album

also If I want to change them using hook_form_alter how can I change the field option and I have add more button

do you have any suggestion
Thanks

Comment: What exactly are the fields that you have?  You should be able to configure a filter to do what you want.

Comment: I have in articles an autocomplete field that display all albums but I need only this field to display albums that never used

Comment: Is this a views question then or a fields question?  If you need the field to always do this, it's a fields question, not a views-specific issue.

Comment: I hope I can make it with views references but If not how can i make it with field using form alter

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not 100% certain if this will work, but I believe you can do this using [`hook_views_pre_execute`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/docs%21docs.php/function/hook_views_pre_execute/6) or [`hook_views_pre_render`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/docs%21docs.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/6). If pre_render gets called for field result options, then you simply need to check the ID's of the `result` array in `$view` and see if they're existing in the database of the field in question, if they do simply `unset()` that result.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... but I used both hooks (pre_excute and pre_render) and try to print_r($view) it print all info if I have a page view or a block view but when I have a reference view (that I used in field reference) it doesn't display any results